# typescript extend an interface as not required

Tags: javascript, interface, typescript

I have two interfaces;

```
interface ISuccessResponse {
    Success: boolean;
    Message: string;
}
```

and

```
interface IAppVersion extends ISuccessResponse {
    OSVersionStatus: number;
    LatestVersion: string;
}
```

I would like to extend ISuccessResponse interface as Not Required;
I can do it as overwrite it but is there an other option?

```
interface IAppVersion {
    OSVersionStatus: number;
    LatestVersion: string;
    Success?: boolean;
    Message?: string;
}
```

I don't want to do this.

Comment: Do you mean you want Success and Message to be optional in IAppVersion?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

A bit late, but Typescript 2.1 introduced the `Partial<T>` type which would allow what you're asking for:

```
interface ISuccessResponse {
    Success: boolean;
    Message: string;
}

interface IAppVersion extends Partial<ISuccessResponse> {
    OSVersionStatus: number;
    LatestVersion: string;
}

declare const version: IAppVersion;
version.Message // Type is string | undefined
```

Answer (score 10):

As of TypeScript 3.5, you could use `Omit`:

```js
interface IAppVersion extends Omit<ISuccessResponse, 'Success' | 'Message'> {
  OSVersionStatus: number;
  LatestVersion: string;
  Success?: boolean;
  Message?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want `Success` and `Message` to be optional, you can do that:

```
interface IAppVersion {
    OSVersionStatus: number;
    LatestVersion: string;
    Success?: boolean;
    Message?: string;
}
```

You ***can't*** use the `extends` keyword to bring in the `ISuccessResponse` interface, but then change the contract defined in that interface (that interface says that they are required).

Answer (score 1):

Your base interface can define properties as optional:

```
interface ISuccessResponse {
    Success?: boolean;
    Message?: string;
}
interface IAppVersion extends ISuccessResponse {
    OSVersionStatus: number;
    LatestVersion: string;
}
class MyTestClass implements IAppVersion {
    LatestVersion: string;
    OSVersionStatus: number;
}
```