# Typescript optionally extending interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I have two `interfaces`, one of which extends the other. However, I would like to be able to extend the first `interface` and make all of its types optional. I don't want to have to rewrite all of the definitions of the first `interface` to be optional in my second `interface` (because what's the advantage of extending at that point?) or redefine the first `interface` because it is being used elsewhere.

What it looks like:

```js
interface First {
  type1: string
  type2: string
}

// Seemingly pointless rewrite (why would I even need to extend?)
interface Second extends First {
  type1?: string
  type2?: string
  type3: string
  type4: string
}

// What I imagine the extending should be (but doesn't work)
interface Second extends First? {
  type3: string
  type4: string
}
```

I did my research and did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650402/typescript-extend-an-interface-as-not-required) that answers something very similar, but it's been a year since that question has been touched and I think my problem is not exactly the same because I want to make the *entire* extended `interface` optional, not just a few types from it.

Is there any way to do this in Typescript, or do I just need to suck it up and make a long second `interface`?

---

### Update (to explain why I'd like to have this work):

I am writing a React web app and have a component that displays an entity from my database in a way that allows the user to edit any value of that entity. I would like my React component to handle the case where the user is creating a new entity, as well as the case where the user is editing an existing entity.

To keep with my above example, let's say that my database entity's values are replicated by the **First** `interface` and the React component uses two passed props that exist in the **Second** `interface`. The React component will *always* have the two values in the **Second**, but not necessarily have the values of the **First**.

In the case of the user creating a new entity, I'd like to construct the React component with only the values of **Second**, without having to specify `null` values for everything in **First**. In the case of the user editing an existing entity, I would pass everything from **First** and **Second**.

In both cases, it would be the same UI, but constructed with a different set of values.

Comment: what is the scenario in your case. Update to post will help you out

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can use [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) along with an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) on the [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) type:

```
type First = {
    type1: string;
    type2: string;
}

type Second = Partial<First> & {
    type3: string;
    type4: string;
}
```

Comment: You're a godsend. That did it for me. In all the time that I've been using DefinitelyTyped, I've ignorantly not noticed the type `type` and have implemented `interface` everywhere in my project(s).

Comment: They are in a lot of cases pretty much the same. Be sure to read [Interfaces vs. Type Aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases) to get a better understanding of how they differ.

Comment: Now that I'm less young and naive, I see the `interface Second extends Partial<First>` works just as well (as shown in Dibyo's answer below)

Comment: How can i do the same with classes?

Answer (score 82):

You can do this with interfaces using the [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) type.

```
interface First {
    type1: string;
    type2: string;
}

interface Second extends Partial<First> {
    type3: string;
    type4: string;
}
```

Comment: This answer works starting from TypeScript version 2.2

Answer (score 18):

There is a better/simpler method. Using [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) you can redefine only the specific named properties.

```
interface First {
    type1: string;
    type2: string;
}

interface Second extends Omit<First, "type1"> {
    type1?: string;
}
```

Comment: Or in this case, you can even use `Pict<First, "type2">` instead of `Omit` the result will be the same

Comment: @JakubKurdziel I believe your approach is not equivalent. The one in this answer has `type1` as optional whereas the approach you listed only has `type2`.

Answer (score 6):

You can also make all parts optional by providing an otherwise empty interface:

```
export interface ISingleScope {
   scope: string;
}

export interface IMultiScope {
   scopes: string[];
   check?: boolean;
}

export interface IProvidedScope 
   extends Partial<ISingleScope>, Partial<IMultiScope> { 
}
```

However, usually this will require an explicit test of the used property exists, as at runtime neither of these information is present. So if your object comes with the name *options* than this would be sufficient:

```
if (options && options.scopes) {
   // access properly 'IMultiScope'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`Partial` is great, but sometimes you want to pick the keys that you want to make optional instead of making them all optional!

To do that, use:
`type Optional<T, K extends keyof T> = Partial<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K>`

Source: This optional answer is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59846133/5248391)
if you need nested optional, go to the linked question.

Answer (score -3):

`Extends` in Typescript `interface` means that the second object will inherit what ever the first object has, if the properties of first one are optional or not they will be applied to the second without changes. You cannot change this behaviour in Typescript.
The answer to you question you should not use `extends` for your case.

Comment: Do you happen to have a suggestion for a different approach? I've already deduced that `extends` is the wrong approach, which is why I asked the question here.

Comment: The only way to implement what you want is putting the first interface as an optional property in the second object. Not sure this would work for you.

Comment: But that would nest **First** inside of an optional property instead of having all of the **First** properties at the root level of **Second**, right? It would work, if that was the case, but it'd be a little more awkward.

Comment: That's right, but as I already told you, either make the first interface's properties optional or redeclare them separately in second.