# Partial<> on specific key

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-typings

I have a typescript interface describing mongodb database data like :

```
interface Foo {
  _id: string,
  name: string,

  fish: {
    _id: string,
    name: string,   
  },
}
```

I have a method that is building one data to insert in the database, like :

```
function pushNewFish() {
   const obj: Foo = {
      name: 'obiwan',

      fish: {
         name: 'kenobi',
      },
  };

  // ...
}
```

**The problem is** : I do not implements every `_id` elements that are specific to database.

I have the possibility to use `Partial<Foo>` but it's not what I'm looking for.

I also have the possibility to turn every `_id: string` into `_id ?: string`, but it feels wrong.

Is there a way to do :

```
interface FooDatabase { ... }

type Foo = Partial<'_id', FooDatabase>;
```

? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you want types like these:

```
type PartialK<T, K extends PropertyKey = PropertyKey> =
  Partial<Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, K>>> & Omit<T, K> extends infer O ?
  { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never;
```

Here, `PartialK<T, K>` acts like `Partial<T>` but only for the keys in `K`, leaving the rest alone.  So `PartialK<T, keyof T>` or `PartialK<T, PropertyKey>` should act like `Partial<T>`.  This should work reasonably well as long as `T` is an object type without index signatures, call signatures, or construct signatures.  I've done a little trick with conditional types so that the resulting object type does not have an intersection in it, like this:

```
type TestPartialK = PartialK<{ a: string, b: number, c: boolean }, "b" | "c">
/* type TestPartialK = {
    b?: number | undefined;
    c?: boolean | undefined;
    a: string;
} */
```

Now that only works one level deep, and it looks like your question wants to do this recursively down through nested objects.  So here's `NestedPartialK<T, K>`:

```
type NestedPartialK<T, K extends PropertyKey = PropertyKey> =
  T extends Function ? T :
  T extends Array<any> ? Array<NestedPartialK<T[number], K>> :
  T extends object ? PartialK<{ [P in keyof T]: NestedPartialK<T[P], K> }, K> :
  T;
```

It uses `PartialK` in its definition; it leaves functions and primitives alone, and uses recursive types to map arrays to arrays, and objects to objects.  Note that it doesn't iterate tuples, but partial tuples are weird anyway and your use case doesn't even mention arrays, so I'm not worried about that much.  Let's see if it works on your `FooDatabase`:

```
type Foo = NestedPartialK<FooDatabase, "_id">
/* type Foo = {
    _id?: string | undefined;
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
    tree: {
        _id?: string | undefined;
        again: {
            _id?: string | undefined;
            value: string;
        };
    };
} */
```

Looks good to me.  All the `_id` props are now optional, and the other props are left alone.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJ2ASzgGwNIB4AqAaKDKCAD2AgDsATAZ1gQHtIkQMIQoBeepiFtkAD4uAKCixEKdFhjIAxgGtcBAKJkEcOcCwL2DAGZR8hQaagAyKAHkAtsm3GMw0uWp1kFfX2tQA-GKgAbygAbRgoDyhdEANrAF0ALmswuKgAXygkiggANz4AbhERUEgoADkIGnIqeCRUTGVCYjJKWh5mUAEudr5O9mFOAJxm1zaAMQBXCi1kBgo-I0yhkda6AEEEDRAsOAohBY2trAqqiBrJeuwcEIoJmwAjPjiCJ2EE5ZdVqAZ7gCsILQLWpSBrBMIRebRWI4RLlSrVYGXXApF7CNKopbiHCFYrgaA4eGI9BEbhE0FQOBJKoIDwAcwI9yyd0eCAIciS9wYDDQEF26QIACJ7gKoAAfKACuQCwQiAD0ACooCV8YSLsTuoEAuJ7r4mQ9vOKplQIPoPGdCuJxHJdVBOdzefNDdQTWaqBbLZSoNS6YUMvLZUUPOQEPpNNAxlyACJwYBwe5wGjQTXiAD6yCoVOANIotPd+i5mezuagAXjCELPqK4izEAgSWTlrTGa9WbpeCrHtpcA89a1jfTFZz7ctlpy6AmdZbReHlrSATnc9xpQjDG6JwRaoaK+jsfjicFTelcsVyqgK41fabNu9ObFUCNLuybr7+YYg9zfbL7-d1YQtd7I4jle753g+ppPj+gFwF2PZBH2gH9lQ16treTrGuB5rwQhUBjmgE7flh4hpJBxEiH6AZFHIcxVFA+hJOe3ANq+SQAOQsTOX5QGx7YBDWk4NuI0HdhQAGAbh+FcSxfZzkRZH5EAA)

Comment: This is a godly answer O:) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

If only certain `_id` fields should be optional then define a new utility type, that only declares the selected keys as optional:

```ts
type Optional<T, K extends keyof T> = Partial<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K>

interface FooDatabase {
  _id: number;
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

type Foo = Optional<FooDatabase, '_id'>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=40#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwDwBUA0UA0lBAB7AQoAmAzlANYQhIBmUOAfFALxQAKaAE6JMWPggDG9XAUIcuAMlgBbBMBlEOAKC0IUFQSzQToAMSRIAImmBoARmhrQA3lqhQA+gioAuKCgBXZTsIQQBuNygWCz8aYEE9AHMI9wdBWPikiIBfHVBIKHMkHlh4ZHRsIutbBycCAHIvKnqOIA)

---

A recursive solution (for nested objects) where each key of the same singleton type is made optional:

```ts
type Primitive = number | string | boolean | undefined | null | any[];
type Optional<T, K extends keyof T> = { [P in K]?: T[P] } & { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P] extends Primitive ? T[P] : Optional<T[P], keyof T[P] & K> };
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAdgVyQCMI4oAfKAZ2EVwHMKoiB7FgGwgENcn9cAJhABmCXBAFMC7dkx4gA2gF0A3AChQkKAHkwaFri7sAPABUANFADSUCAA9gEQVSgBrCCBbCopgHxQcAG8oBRgoMWslAH4ALh9QpSgAXygAMihg0PDeAFE7AGN2fCFjd09vC2tfJTjTBNsHJwEXeGRUDGgo+JhEuN19QxM6nssyr27E9Kt-JPU1MUc4YS586AAxNgARLmAuIi4qaEC1KCgAfQQBOJo6enVT4TZr2jF6ZXvmLjhn27nT2ggEDix1OpwuV2oLwY5jUJ1BXHoXDEwLhoPOlx+rxhaNO6CM+CBkNulhxqOScKSakpGnA6zYAR0egQBiMxg2LG2u32h0sAHJwbzfLDOMAoMI4uyGSCxU8QkpsZ9vlBebyYXCAYTpacEUjcCicVA8UVCSqyZTTpTZkA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it looks promising. I've tried a schema containing multiple level of nested keys [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=29&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwDwBUA0UA0lBAB7AQoAmAzlANYQhIBmUOAfFALxQAKaAE6JMWPggDG9XAUIcuAMlgBbBMBlEOAKC0IUFQSzQToAMSRIAImmBoARmhrQA3lqhQA+gioAuKDWBBPQBzAG43KBYLPwCglDCIh0EYwJDwiMCICD9Xd3cvX39U+LwdPKg0YLQ9HIjygpS44NLy9wA3TABXbKKmgla6qABfCJGRrVBIKHMkHlh4ZHRsGetbBycCAHICze0tCVQAyL8ZudzI6KhNzZaoJL9r0ozBLNryyuqUN9aOjG6HzaDEbuMahIA) Unfortunately I get an error at the third level.

Comment: I added a recursive version, in which the same key within a nested object is made optional.